# Grails: How to dynamically change method signature in scaffolded code depending on Domain id type?

Tags: grails, scaffolding

I'm trying to build a grails (2.1.0) application on top of a legacy database. It has a ton of tables, and I'd like very much to use only dynamic scaffolding. The issue is that some of the tables have a string as primary key, but template code in src/templates/scaffolding/Controller.groovy for e.g. show is

```
def show(Long id) {
    def ${propertyName} = ${className}.get(id)
    if (!${propertyName}) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: '${domainClass.propertyName}.label', default: '${className}'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [${propertyName}: ${propertyName}]
}
```

For the string keys, this seems to turn the string into null, and the get fails with the error `$Domain not found with id null`.

If I run a generate-controller and change the signature to `def show(String id)`, it works as expected.

So, is there a way to inspect the domain class at "dynamic scaffolding time" and write the method accordingly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the controller template you have a `domainClass` variable that gives you access to the `GrailsDomainClass` representing the class for which you are generating the controller, so you can do something like this (and likewise for `edit`, `update` and `delete`):

```
def show(${domainClass.identifier.type.name} id) {
```

which should generate `def show(java.lang.Long id)` or `def show(java.lang.String id)` as appropriate.